# Not seeing Nuxt / Axios progress bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

The [Nuxt / Axios integration documentation](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) is sparse, to say the least, but it seems to suggest that the Nuxt progress bar is automatically integrated with Axios. But I'm not seeing it. I sometimes see the progress bar pop up when going from page to page, but not during an Axios fetch.

My app is an SPA.

Am I doing something wrong? What do I have to do to make it appear?

My Axios config in nuxt.config.js has almost nothing in it (just setting baseURL and the timeout), and in my pages I'm just doing plain-vanilla fetches to the server:

```js
mounted() {
  this.$axios.get("/users/" + auth.getUser().user_id).then(
    response => {
      this.user = response.data;
    },
    error => {
      util.showAxiosError("Failed to fetch user", error);
    }
  );
}
```

**Update:**

If I manually add "this.$nuxt.$loading.start()" before I call this.$axios.get(), the progress bar still doesn't appear during the Axios fetch. It appears only briefly during the page transition. If I put this:

```
loading: {
  color: "blue",
  height: "5px"
},
```

per the documentation, then the progress bar that appears briefly does correctly have this style.

**Another update:**

If I try `this.$nuxt.$loading.start();` on its own, without axios, it *does* work. So, somehow axios is turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the loading code in an `mounted()` lifecycle hook? Then it will only appear once.

The other thing is if you dont know:

Unfortunately, it is not possible for the Loading component to know in advance how long loading a new page will take. Therefore, it is not possible to accurately animate the progress bar to 100% of the loading time.

The loading bar is just styling, nothing more. You need to tell on your own how long it will take with

```
 this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
```

And

```
 this.$nuxt.$loading.end()
```

Comment: "Did you put the loading code in an mounted() lifecycle hook? Then it will only appear once." Not sure what this means. The progress bar fails to be triggered by an axios call whether it's in a mounted() hook or not.